# Where can I find the rule definitions for "eslint:recommended"?

Tags: rules, eslint

In a `.eslintrc` file, we can use:

```
"extends": "eslint:recommended"
```

to extend the recommended rules provided by eslint, and in [the rule list](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/), many of them are marked as "recommended".

My question what is the exact rule definitions for them? I searched in the repo of [eslint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint), but not found it.

Answer (score 60):

Freewind's answer is pointing to a specific commit – now outdated.

All rules are listed here https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/. from the list you can easily find the `eslint:recommnded` rules - **as they are marked with this icon**: ✅

Comment: Outdated, see Pere's answer for correct answer as of 2023-03-07.

Answer (score 15):

As of today (February 2023), the list can be found in this file:

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/main/packages/js/src/configs/eslint-recommended.js

Answer (score 8):

Run this terminal command from the project root to output a complete list of definitions being applied in your setup.

```sh
./node_modules/.bin/eslint --print-config *.* > "./.eslintrc.js_fullsettings.js"
```

If you only have `extends: ['eslint:recommended']` in the `.eslint` file you'll get what you're looking for.

Comment: "The --print-config option must be used with exactly one file name."

Comment: The only thing I can think of is maybe you don't have a .eslint config file in the root? Or you have more than one config? Sorry. I haven't had this issue on any of my projects. They all have a `.eslintrc.js` in the root. This may not work with configs at multiple places in the tree.

Comment: Getting "The --print-config option must be used with exactly one file name."

Comment: According to the [doc](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--print-config) you should specify a file, and eslint tells you the configuration to be used for it. `*.*` does not make sense.

Answer (score 6):

All entries with a checkmark in this list: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/

Answer (score 4):

There's a list [here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/conf/eslint-recommended.js).

---

#### Old answer

[Eslint no longer shows the list of recommended rules in a single file](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/dccee63cf41234180c71bf0fe01b165c9078fc69/conf/eslint-recommended.js), so here's a way to get the current list with Node.js:

```
const { Linter } = require('eslint')
const rules = [...new Linter().getRules().entries()] // all rules
  .filter(data => data[1].meta.docs.recommended)     // filter out unrecommended
  .map(data => data[0])                              // get rule names
console.log(rules.join('\n'))
```

[Here's a live example](https://repl.it/@Purpzie/eslint-recommended-rules) that can also create an object that basically represents the entire recommended config, a handy markdown chart, or just a simple list of rule names if that's what you need.

Comment: This [later commit](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/commit/f42d0afd89874b459fce1eb1998247d53f9aa42b#diff-ba6ef5865cfaa7efd6dfe5089d85709e) reverted the one you linked to, and now the rules are again [in one file](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/conf/eslint-recommended.js). Nice live example though!

Answer (score 3):

From the source code, I found:

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/3642d0bb6ced17eeed50c030531a3ddbeb939f29/lib/config.js#L189-L192

So the real config is here: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/3642d0bb6ced17eeed50c030531a3ddbeb939f29/conf/eslint.json